# Get Value Joined 2 Table with Getter in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

Trying to get value from 2 joined tables with getter, have 2 models `Customer` and `Address`.

```java
@Setter
@Getter
@Data
@Entity
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "phoneNumber")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
}
```

```java
@Setter
@Getter
@Data
@Entity
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "zipcode")
    private String zipcode;

    @Column(name = "number")
    private Integer number;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customer")//
    private Customer customerBean;
}
```

Address Repository with this query :

```java
@Query( value = "SELECT ad FROM Address ad, Customer c WHERE ad.customer = c.id and c.id = 1)
Optional <List<Address>> getAddress();
```

Try to get with getter :

```java
Optional<List<Address>> address = getAddress();
System.out.println(address.getAddress()); //success
System.out.println(address.getAddress().get().get(0).getCustomerBean().getName()) //null value
```

Successfully get data address from table `Address`, but if get `Customer` name get `null` value, any suggestion?

Comment: You have `@Table(name = "documents")` in both entities. Is this a typo?

Comment: Yes typo, question has edited

Comment: Since you have used @Data annotations, no need to use Setter & Getter annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in your `@Query` definition:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT ad FROM Address ad JOIN FETCH ad.customer WHERE ad.customer = 1")
Optional <List<Address>> getAddress();
```